# how to backup EFI boot entries

Tags: boot, backup, uefi

I have two hard drives with Arch Linux and Windows 10 installed respectively in UEFI mode. Let's say they are disk1 and disk2. Now I want to try Hackintosh on disk2, overwriting existing windows install. Before all that, I want to make a full backup of disk2 including its EFI boot entry or maybe entire EFI boot entry table.

I have created a image of disk2 with dd under linux:

```
dd if=disk2 conv=sync status=progress bs=64K | gzip -c > $(date -Idate).gz
```

Now, how to backup EFI boot entries? I can see with `efibootmgr` you can only list or add boot entries. Or, do I really need to make a backup, since disk2's ESP partition is already included in the disk image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm *well* familiar with this situation -- 100's of (hackintosh) installs.

That said; WARNING Windows is really pissy in this situation. You have been warned!

Additional information is required for as *definitive* answer. eg; GPT vs MBR. Partition layout, ...

But, the short answer; You're going to (probably) need to change your EFI boot loader. Which means you're *really* only going to need to backup your EFI partition. This, in case the new EFI bootloader install doesn't recognize your *other* (current) installs. Which will *usually* only mean that you need mount your EFI partition, and copy the files from your backup into the current EFI partition. Clover, Chameleon, and Enoch are the current choices for Hackintosh installs. I think if you research those, you'll be well on your way to understanding what you'll need to accomplish your task.

Good luck!

P.S. you should be able to mount your current EFI, as well as your *future* EFI partition from either your current Linux install, or nearly any *live* Linux dist. Which will then allow you to manipulate it's (EFI) contents.